# HTML/JS Rich Text Editor Pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg, medium-editor

I'm looking on how to implement pagination/page breaks with page formats (A4, letter, etc.) using a rich text editor (like [the Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor)).

The font family, font size, line height, margins are going to be fixed, as this is a very specific case study. I'm thinking of handling zoom levels in pure CSS (scale), instead of directly modifying widths, heights, etc.

Also, for the sake of the experiment, say I'll be running this in Chrome only & browser rendering differences aren't really an issue (but even if I were building this for various browsers, I'd try and use more precise units, such as "px", "em" for the font-sizes, page widths, margins between elements, etc. - probably just "px").

Keep in mind I'm not asking about "@page" rules or print rules, I know how to achieve what I want with those when I print out a PDF, but rather direct in-browser implementation. Printing should (and will) be handled by "@page" and I got no issue to handle page breaks there when I need them.

In the end, my question is - where do I start?

I imagine taking into account word-count and "h(1,2,3...)", "p" tag margins, along with case-specific CSS rules (break-after, break-word, break-line, etc) - even though taking those into account with js probably won't be very easy.

Probably even include the page height? Say, if the format is A4: 596px x 842px (72dpi) - take it into account when the total height of "each" element inside the page == height of page - [sum of bottom and top page margins]?

Other than the latter (with a simple js loop), if someone has any pointers, or maybe even a code snippet (or a plugin?), I'd be very grateful! Thank you!

Comment: After reading through this, I would be thinking you could set up hidden div, with margins, font-family, font-size etc set to scale on it, pass your content to it from editor on keypress, and trigger and event of adding a page break once last paragraph's bottom border reaches certain point. Word count and letter count sounds quite interesting, yet hard to account on unless you are using monospaced font.